Please don't hide information by editing Links to non-descript linktexts
Lately, there has been doing a lot of minor touch up editing, mostly adding code markers, removing of extraneous text and other improvements of readability. It is much appreciated.
One thing, however, might be counter-productive: There have been quite a few edits that suggest to set a link providing background information for a question under a non-descript linktext.
For example

I followed the steps for PC from here: http://cryptocur.com/litecoin/litecoin-mining/

becomes 

I followed the steps for PC from here

Example taken from Miner seems to be stuck at receiving new blocks.
Such an edit hides interesting information: I'd rather see the source of (relevant) information without having to click an unknown link or having to move the mouse to hover over it.
A better solution would be to either put a sufficient description instead or to leave the link intact if it isn't too much clutter.

Ambiguous to demonstrate obtuse nature I agree Murch. It's one thing to click on hazards to your mental sovereignty, it's a whole 'nother can't of worms when it's a wormhole-hyperlink that's obfuscated by the innocuous "... Here." 
I appreciate all of your continued efforts. I will do my best to submit answers in accordance with these and other shrewd guidelines that you faithfully set forth.
-YourGenesisBloke
